# Type inference in Java 7, When and why should it be used?

Tags: java, generics, java-7, type-inference

```
@Test
public void TypeInferenceTest() {
    inference();
    uncheckedAssignment();
    explicit();
}

private void inference() {
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("abc");
    String s = strings.get(0);

    assertThat(s, is("abc"));
}

private void uncheckedAssignment() {
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList();
    strings.add("abc");
    String s = strings.get(0);

    assertThat(s, is("abc"));
}

private void explicit() {
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    strings.add("abc");
    String s = strings.get(0);

    assertThat(s, is("abc"));
}
```

The code above used three ways to instantiate a list: type inference, open generic type and closed generic type.

But if I decompile the generated bytecode using JD-GUI, this is the result:

```
  @Test
  public void TypeInferenceTest() {
    inference();
    uncheckedAssignment();
    explicit();
  }

  private void inference() {
    ArrayList strings = new ArrayList();
    strings.add("abc");
    String s = (String)strings.get(0);

    Assert.assertThat(s, Matchers.is("abc"));
  }

  private void uncheckedAssignment() {
    ArrayList strings = new ArrayList();
    strings.add("abc");
    String s = (String)strings.get(0);

    Assert.assertThat(s, Matchers.is("abc"));
  }

  private void explicit() {
    ArrayList strings = new ArrayList();
    strings.add("abc");
    String s = (String)strings.get(0);

    Assert.assertThat(s, Matchers.is("abc"));
  }
```

Looks like they generated the same bytebote.

So when and why should we use type inference instead of the other two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others have covered why it generates the same code.  So, to answer the actual question - the short answer is to prefer this:

```
   ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

Because it's briefer than this, while conveying the same meaning (to humans and to the compiler):

```
   ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But avoids unnecessarily causing a warning like this:

```
   ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList();
```

As for being briefer, this:

```
   ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Isn't that bad, and there's no real harm in typing it out (after all, we've all been doing it for years).  But if you wind up writing something like:

```
   Map<String, Map<Widget<Spork>, Bar<Llama>>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

It becomes far more tedious if you have to type this twice:

```
<String, Map<Widget<Spork>, Bar<Llama>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

The type inference is just a shortcut for an unnecessarily long way of instantiating paremeterized types. Generics are still implemented by type-erasure, so your bytecode will only have the raw types.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I beg to differ. Type inference is just shortcut; if your bytecode doesn't have type info, your decompiled code will reflect that. So, making the, now easy to see, point that it makes not difference between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

As your example demonstrates, Java generics are implemented by [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and generic code is no different from non-generic code at runtime. This makes generics purely a compile-time feature - added type safety for the benefit of the developer.

In the case of your example, there's really no difference between `new ArrayList()`, `new ArrayList<String>()`, and `new ArrayList<>()` - all that matters is the type of the variable it gets assigned to. Using `new ArrayList()` is still discouraged because it *looks* like legacy code and may confuse another developer. It will cause compilers/IDEs to show the standard "raw types" warning and is therefore distracting. But that's it, for a no-arg constructor at least.

However, providing a type argument or using type inference really is important for any constructor that takes generic arguments. Consider this example:

```
Collection<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

List<String> strings1 = new ArrayList(ints);         // compiles!
List<String> strings2 = new ArrayList<String>(ints); // won't compile
List<String> strings3 = new ArrayList<>(ints);       // won't compile
```

As for why to use `new ArrayList<>(ints)` over `new ArrayList<String>(ints)`, well, it's less verbose and avoids repeating the generic type already specified in the variable being assigned to.